# Running multiple animations on one image simultaneously

Tags: android, image

Ok so my question is how can I get one image to be effected by multiple tweens like alpha and rotate. right now it is only doing the alpha and I want it to spin while it flashes.

```
package com.example.minecraft;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Tween extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tween);
        ImageView imgRotate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgTween);
        imgRotate.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation));
        imgRotate.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha));
    }
}
```

That is how I am trying it right now any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run multiple animations a same object by using `AnimationSet`
for eg:

```
AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);//false mean dont share   interpolators
s.addAnimation(anim1);
s.addAnimation(anim2);
imageView.startAnimation(s);
```

or you can defined animations on xml and load it on run time check [link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/02/multi-animation-in-one-set.html)